# "The network path was not found" - shortening the delay before Windows tries again

Tags: windows, file-sharing

If I try to connect (over Windows file sharing) to a machine that has gone to sleep, I get a timeout followed by "The network path was not found".  If I then wake the machine and try again, I still get "The network path was not found" because the connection failure has been cached.  If I wait 30 seconds from the initial failure (I've timed this) and then try again I can connect successfully.

I understand this behaviour.  My question is: is there any way to shorten the delay before I can try the connection again?

Comment: Have you tried installing the hotfix from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2663418 ?

Comment: Which Windows version are the 2 computers? And is the network adapter on the sleeping one allowed to wake up the computer?

Comment: @harrymc: Windows 7 x64 SP1.  The network adapter is configured to wake on receiving a magic packet, but that's not really relevant to the question.  If the two machines are in the same room, I can reproduce this behaviour just as easily without using WOL.

Comment: @Adam: thanks for the suggestion.  Installing that hotfix did not reduce the timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

Another shot in the dark:

Locate and then click the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet
```

Click the Control subkey
Right-click the `ServicesPipeTimeout DWORD` value, and then click modify -> decimal -> type 60000 (for 60s) -> ok (in your case I would try 10s so: 10000)

If the ServicesPipeTimeout value is not available add the new DWORD value.

I saw this here: [Original Article](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1446599)

Comment: ATTENTION: That's actually the time that the Service Control Manager waits before terminating a starting service and it affects the functioning of all system services. Shortening it could have unpredictable effects including the premature termination of slow-to-start services. Absolutely not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark:

The [SESSTIMEOUT parameter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102067) is apparently still functional on later Windows versions.
I base this assumption on the fact that this parameter is [mentioned here](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=4142975&prodTypeId=18964&objectID=c02852962&printver=true) for Server 2008.

The parameter is found in the registry at :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`

SESSTIMEOUT is of type DWORD and its value is the number of seconds. Changes are supposed
to take effect immediately, but I would still reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Lowering SESSTIMEOUT to 10 seconds did not reduce the timeout period.  Looking at the documentation, I think SESSTIMEOUT probably only applies to activity on established sessions, rather than to establishing new sesssions.

Comment: Another long shot: See [SMB2 Client Redirector Caches Explained](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Try in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Lanmanworkstation\Parameters` to create (if not already there) the DWORD values of `DirectoryCacheLifetime`, `FileNotFoundCacheLifetime`, `FileInfoCacheLifetime` and setting them all to zero for no caching. Create first a system restore point, just in case.

Comment: No change, but that article could explain some other odd behaviour I've noticed in certain applications in Windows 7.  Thanks!

Comment: Since this doesn't solve my original problem I haven't marked it as the answer, but bounty awarded because the referenced articles were useful in other respects.